# How do I save the column order of a SubForm once the database is saved as an ACCDE?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Form with a SubForm on it. The SubForm "Default View" is Datasheet.

When I run (open) the Form, I am able to reorder the columns of the SubForm and the new column positions are saved between runs.

Once I save the database as an ACCDE, the column positions no longer retain their order between runs. They always revert to the original order.

I tried saving the Form and SubForm in the Unload event of the Form:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  DoCmd.Close acForm, resultsSub.Name, acSaveYes
  DoCmd.Save acForm, Name
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to save column positions in a SubForm Datasheet of an ACCDE?

Comment: Since this is somehow part of the design of the form,I doubt you are allowed to save that in a compiled version.

Comment: Yes, you will have to save the column order in a table when closing the form, and read them when opening the form and reorder the columns. This must be done in a local table or by storing also the User ID.

Comment: Good example of setting column order of Datasheet in VBA at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa224067(v=office.11) - but like @Gustav said you'll have to save the column order into a table or even the form's tag property to read/reset when the datasheet form opens the next time

Comment: Thank you, @gustav. That's the answer I needed.